# Python: Open PSD images (Django form)

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, psd

is there a way to get size and content type of a PSD image while cleaning its form field? 
The Image.open() raises this error:

```
IOError: cannot identify image file <InMemoryUploadedFile: Untitled-1.psd (image/vnd.adobe.photoshop)>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psd-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue might be because the file is still in memory. With an example PSD saved off the internet, I'm able to use the `file` command which returns the following:

```
$ file 05.psd 
05.psd: Adobe Photoshop Image, 800 x 800, RGB, 3x 8-bit channels
```

Therefore, I think you're going to need to save the file to the file system at "cleaning time", and then analyse it with `Image`.